# Angular controller structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner with AngularsJs and I've got a question about the controller structure.

This is my `employeeController.js`

```
    (function()
    {
        angular.module('employeeApp').controller('employeeController', employeeController);

        function employeeController(employeeFactory,$routeParams,departmentFactory,schoolFactory,mentorFactory,constants,$location,$scope) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.employee = null;
            vm.employees = null;
            vm.profilePicture = null;
            vm.mentors = null;
            vm.schools = null;
            vm.departments = null;
            vm.roleId = constants.roleid;
            vm.internEducators = null;

            vm.overviewMentors = function() {
                mentorFactory.overview(constants.companyid).then(function(response)
                {
                    vm.mentors = response;
                });
            }

            vm.create = function()
            {
                employeeFactory.create(vm.employee,vm.profilePicture).success(function(response,status)
                {
                    if(status == 200)
                    {
                        $.toaster({message: 'De werknemer is toegevoegd'});
                        $location.path('/home');
                    }
                    }).error(function(response)
                    {
                        var i = 0;
                        vm.error = response;

                        angular.forEach(response.result.message, function(error)
                        {
                            if(i <= 2)
                            {
                                $.toaster({ priority: 'danger', message: error});
                            }
                            i++;
                        });
                    });
            }

            vm.overviewInternEducators = function() {
                employeeFactory.overviewInternEducators(constants.companyid).then(function(response)
                {
                    vm.internEducators = response;
                });
            }

            vm.overviewSchools = function() {
                schoolFactory.overview(constants.companyid).then(function(response)
                {
                    if(angular.isDefined(response[0].SchoolId))
                    {
                        vm.schools = response;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('leeg!');
                    }
                });
            }

            vm.overviewDepartments = function() {
                console.log('test');
                departmentFactory.overview(constants.companyid).then(function(response)
                {
                    vm.departments = response;
                });
            }

            vm.show = function() {
                vm.isAdmin = employeeFactory.isAdmin();
                employeeFactory.show($routeParams.id).then(function(response)
                {
                    vm.employee = response;
                });
            }

            vm.showDeleted = function() {
                employeeFactory.showDeleted($routeParams.id).then(function(response)
                {
                    vm.employee = response;
                });
            }

            vm.update = function()
            {
                employeeFactory.update(vm.employee, vm.profilePicture).success(function(response, status)
                {
                    if(status == 200)
                    {
                        vm.show(); // Zodat de nieuwe afbeelding wordt weergegeven
                        $.toaster({ message: 'De werknemer is geupdated' });
                    }
                }).error(function(response)
                {
                    var i = 0;
                    vm.error = response;

                    angular.forEach(response.result.message, function(error)
                    {
                        if(i <= 2)
                        {
                            $.toaster({ priority: 'danger', message: error});
                        }
                        i++;
                    });
                });
            }

            vm.overviewDeleted = function() {
                employeeFactory.overviewDeleted().then(function(response)
                {
                    if(angular.isDefined(response[0].EmployeeId))
                    {
                        vm.employees = response;
                    }
                });
            }

            vm.delete = function() {
                employeeFactory.delete($routeParams.id).then(function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'true')
                    {
                        $.toaster({ message: 'De werknemer is verwijderd' });

                        $location.path('/home');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.forEach(response, function(error)
                        {
                            $.toaster({ priority: 'danger', message: error });
                        });
                    }
                });

            }

            vm.permanentDelete = function(employeeId) {
                employeeFactory.permanentDelete(employeeId).then(function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'true')
                    {
                        $.toaster({ message: 'De werknemer is permanent verwijderd' });

                        $location.path('/prullenbak/werknemers');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.forEach(response, function(error)
                        {
                            $.toaster({ priority: 'danger', message: error });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        vm.restore = function(employeeId) {
            employeeFactory.restore(employeeId).then(function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'true')
                {
                    $.toaster({ message: 'De werknemer is teruggezet' });
                    $location.path('/werknemer/' + employeeId);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(angular.isArray(response))
                    {
                        angular.forEach(response, function(error)
                        {
                            $.toaster({ priority : 'danger', message : error[0]});
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        <!--ng-init-->
        vm.editEmployee = function()
        {
            vm.show();
            vm.overviewDepartments();
            vm.overviewInternEducators();
            vm.overviewMentors();
            vm.overviewSchools();
        }

        vm.createEmployee = function() {
            vm.overviewMentors();
            vm.overviewSchools();
            vm.overviewDepartments();
            vm.overviewInternEducators();
        }

        <!--redirects-->
        vm.editRedirect = function(werknemerId)
        {
            $location.path('/werknemer/edit/' + werknemerId);
        }

        vm.showTrashedEmployeeRedirect = function(werknemerId)
        {
            $location.path('/prullenbak/werknemer/' + werknemerId);
        }
    }
})()
```

As you can see I use 2 methods called `editEmployee` and `createEmployee` (at the end). I use these 2 with the `create employee` page and the `edit employee page`. On both pages there are a couple of comboboxes that have to be loaded. In for example my create employee page I say `ng-init="employeeController.createEmployee()"` and then those comboboxes are filled.

I know this is not the best approach so how could I do this on a different and better way?

Comment: Thanks @jamie What exactly do you want help on? Is it the loading of the combo boxes or the whole structure of the app or `controller` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically the structure of the controller.

Comment: Hi. I suggest you to check [John Papa's Angular 1 style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and, in particular, the [controller section](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers).

Comment: I have given an example in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to structure you app but the style guide endorsed by the Angular team is maintained by John Papa.
Refer to [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) by John Papa.
Based on that:

First I would suggest that you split the `create`, `show`, `edit` and `delete` functionality into separate `controllers`. This helps with ensuring each controller does only one **single** thing.This is in line with the idea of [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Secondly since it seems you are using the `controllerAs` syntax you wouldn't need to inject scope into your controller.

Here is the code for creating an employee(sth like `create-employee.controller.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
   angular.module('employeeApp').controller('CreateEmployeeController', CreateEmployeeController);
  //ngInject is used to help create minify safe version of the file during the build process.
 //You should have this somewhere in your build process
/** @ngInject **/
function CreateEmployeeController(constants, departmentFactory, employeeFactory, $location, mentorFactory, schoolFactory) {
var vm = this;
vm.create = create;
getMentors();
getSchools();
getDepartments();
getInternEducators();

function getMentors() {
  return mentorFactory.overview(constants.companyid).then(function (response) {
    vm.mentors = response;
  });
}

function getSchools() {
  return schoolFactory.overview(constants.companyid).then(function (response) {
    if (angular.isDefined(response[0].SchoolId)) {
      vm.schools = response;
    }
    else {
      console.log('leeg!');
    }
  });
}

function getDepartments() {
  return departmentFactory.overview(constants.companyid).then(function (response) {
    vm.departments = response;
  });
}

function getInternEducators() {
  return employeeFactory.overviewInternEducators(constants.companyid).then(function (response) {
    vm.internEducators = response;
  });
}
}

function create() {
return employeeFactory.create(vm.employee, vm.profilePicture).success(function (response, status) {
  if (status == 200) {
    $.toaster({message: 'De werknemer is toegevoegd'});
    $location.path('/home');
  }
}).error(function (response) {
  var i = 0;
  vm.error = response;

  angular.forEach(response.result.message, function (error) {
    if (i <= 2) {
      $.toaster({priority: 'danger', message: error});
    }
    i++;
  });
});
}
})();
```

You would then create the other controllers by splitting the functionality following this example.

Comment: Thankyou! Very useful. One more question the methods getMentors,getSchools,getDepartments are also used in edit employee. Should I just duplicate those methods?

Comment: @Jamie, That's something that I honestly do not know have a good answer to. I am leaning towards having them in a  factory i.e.`angular.module('myModule').factory('')` and getting them in the controller i.e by injecting them in the controller. Another option is to repeat them in each controller but that goes against the DRY principle(Don't repeat yourself). 
Will dig into this and give an answer